# Update all timestamps with a given year in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to update my table and add 4 years to each timestamp where the year is 2010. I am using postgresql.

```
x    |  y     

c    | 2010-05-08 16:23:00
d    | 2011-01-01 01:23:45
```

desired result :

```
x    |  y    

c    | 2014-05-08 16:23:00 
d    | 2011-01-01 01:23:45
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update the_table
   set y = y + interval '4' year
where extract(year from y) = 2010;
```